# I don't see clickable links in WebStorm JavaScript debug console

Tags: javascript, debugging, webstorm, stack-trace

My stack trace in WebStorm 11 debug console looks like this:

[image: Webstorm screenshot]

I don't know why i don't see clickable @ links. 
In Chrome console it looks like this:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

JS used for test:

```
<script>
  function baz() { bar(); }
  function bar() { foo(); }
  function foo() { makeError(); }

  baz();
</script>
```

Comment: Works fine for me - the links are displayed on the right side of the console window. Unfortunately, can't see that side of the tool window on your screenshot.

Comment: @EkaterinaPrigara   Unfortunately, there are no links on the right. I noticed that the problem is only in WebStorm 11, even after new installation on other machine. In WebStorm 9 everything is fine.

Comment: Tried that in WebStorm 11.0.3, seemed fine too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to WebStorm 2016.1 resolved problem.